# Apache Tomcat 10.0.0-M1 using JSP Absolute uri http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans-11

I have tried everything in the multiple threads on this site (non of them were for Tomcat 10 and non of the solved problem.  I am using Apache NetBeans 11.1 with Apache Tomcat 10.0.0-M1. Below is my configuration -- if I remove the taglib line from my jsp file, the error goes away.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
           <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
           <version>3.3.1</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <!--scope>provided</scope-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

test.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Results</h1>
        <testResults></testResults>
    </body>
</html>
```

error displayed:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:431)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:489)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1445)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:955)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found out that on Tomcat 10 you can use apache-taglibs 1.2.5 migrated with tomcat migration tool with jakarta-jstl-api 2.0, or use glassfish jstl implementation, that works just fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can not use "Glassfish JSTL implementation" with Tomcat 10.0.7 which released on 2021-06-15. However, the above implementation works fine with Tomcat 10.0.6 which has moved into the apache archive directory.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Tomcat team gave me the solution via e-mail (Thanks Mark):

> From the Tomcat 10.0.0-M1 release announcement:
>
> Users of Tomcat 10 onwards should be aware that, as a result
>   of the move from Java EE to Jakarta EE as part of the transfer of Java
>   EE to the Eclipse Foundation, the primary package for all implemented
>   APIs has changed from javax.* to jakarta.*. This will almost certainly
>   require code changes to enable applications to migrate from Tomcat 9
>   and earlier to Tomcat 10 and later.
>
> > ```
> >         <dependency>
> >
> >             <groupId>javax</groupId>
> >
> >             <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
> >
> >             <version>8.0.1</version>
> >
> >             <scope>provided</scope>
> >
> >         </dependency>
> > ```
>
> That is never going to work on Tomact 10. You can't use Java EE 8
>   libraries with a Jakarta EE 9 server.
>
> > ```
> >         <dependency>
> >
> >             <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
> >
> >             <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
> >
> >             <version>1.4.7</version>
> >
> >             <type>jar</type>
> >
> >         </dependency>
> > ```
>
> That needs to be replaced with Jakarta Mail (there might be an RC for
>   that on Maven Central)
>
> > ```
> >         <dependency>
> >
> >             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
> >
> >             <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
> >
> >             <version>5.1.10.RELEASE</version>
> >
> >         </dependency>
> > ```
>
> That won't work and, as far as I am aware, there is no Jakarta EE 9
>   version available (or even being worked on) yet.
>
> > ```
> >         <dependency>
> >
> >             <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
> >
> >             <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
> >
> >             <version>1.2</version>
> >
> >             <!--scope>provided</scope-->
> >
> >         </dependency>
> > ```
>
> You need the Jakarta Standard Tag Library 2.0 or later. I think that
>   is one of the Jakarta projects struggling for active committers.
>
> Tomcat 10 ships with an API and implementation for the Jakarta
>   Standard Tag Library 2.0 in the examples web application. It was
>   created by taking the JSTL 1.2 JARs and running them through Tomcat's
>   Java EE 8 to Jakarta EE 9 conversion / migration tool.
>
> > test.jsp
>
> Might sticking with Tomcat 9 be a better option for you for now?
>
> Mark