# java- jstl in spring mvc is giving JstlCoreTLV cast error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

I am trying to use jstl in my java spring mvc project.

here is the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I have added the following line to use jstl in my jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

but when i am trying to access that page it is giving me following error.

```
class org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator
```

does anyone has any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After searching about it i found out that there is some jakarta migration issue with the tomcat10 server. which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490478/apache-tomcat-10-0-0-m1-using-jsp-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core#:%7E:text=Tomcat%2010%20ships%20with%20an,EE%209%20conversion%20%2F%20migration%20tool).

so we can use glassfish jstl implementation:

```
dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

with addition of this dependency error was solved.